# find trail and leading records in oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get trailing and leading records upto 3 to matched condition.
I want to get

```
empid          last_nm
----------- -------------------------
        179 Johnson                  
        180 Taylor Maddy
        178 Grant Son                    
        34  John                  
        180 Taylor Ross
        178 Mia                    
        179 Rocky
```

How to add here 
Eg:`select * from emp where empid=34`
i get only `emp_id` as 34 and `last_nm` as John

`emp` table contains records

```
empid          last_nm
----------- -------------------------
        178 Graham                    
        179 Johnson                  
        180 Taylor Maddy
        178 Grant Son                    
        34  John                  
        180 Taylor Ross
        178 Mia                    
        179 Rocky                  
        180 Siva
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column and the `MAX() OVER ()` analytic function:

```
SELECT empid,
       last_nm
FROM   (
  SELECT e.*,
         MAX( CASE WHEN empid = 34 THEN ROWNUM END ) OVER () AS matched_rn,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   employees e
)
WHERE  rn BETWEEN matched_rn - 3 AND matched_rn + 3;
```